# What is the difference between Disco Info (#info) and Disco Items (#items) in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, service-discovery

I've been attempting to read [XEP-0030 Service Discovery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html) but found the language pretty opaque.

My question is simple: What is the difference between the `disco#info` spec and the `disco#items` spec?

My guess is to say that disco#info is the request and disco#items is the response but that does not seem to match up to the way I am interpreting the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically:

- `#info` is used to discover [information about a XMPP entity.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info)
- `#item` is used to discover [items associated with a XMPP entity.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#items)

`#info` query results will show you amongst others the supported features of a XMPP entity (e.g. [XHTML-IM support](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html#discovery-explicit)).

`#item` query results will show the available items of a XMPP entity. For example the [XEP-0045 MUC component](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-service) of a XMPP service. But any other available service/component could show up here.

One could also say that `#info` is used to query the features of this particular entity, while `#items` is used to query for "sub-components" of that entity, which itself are usually be queried with `#info` for their features.

Comment: Cheers for cleaning up my question but the way but I'm wondering if you can clarify something: `#info` requests supported features and `#item` requests available features. So you could have a feature that is supported but not available? But I suppose you couldn't have features that aren't supported but are available? Or are these XMPP entities potentially different kinds of entities?

Comment: No, you always relate` `#item` with features, but this is wrong and seems to confuse you. `#item` just used to discover items (e.g. components) not features.

Comment: Ah, so the difference is that `#info` lists features which are client side supported and `#item` lists components which are server side supported? Is that along the right lines?

Comment: That is nearly correct: `#item` can be used von every XMPP entity, not just server services.